# SwiftUI: "Dynamic List with groups" not refreshed when an `@Published` property is changed

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I am trying to create a ***dynamic grouped List*** in SwiftUI and I am facing an issue where if I change the collection that is mark as @Published of the inner ForEach that change is not visible in the UI unless I go to a different screen/sheet. I do not understand if what I am doing is correct or incorrect bug there are very limited resources on the topic of "dynamic grouped List in SwiftUI" so I am hoping you to point me in the right direction.

Here is my setup:

Model:

```swift
class Product: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Category: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var items = [Product]()
    var categoryName = ""
}

class Categories: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Category]()
}
```

and the View

```swift
struct ProductListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var categories: Categories = Categories()


    var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(categories.items) { category in
                    Section(header: Text(category.categoryName)) {
                        ForEach(category.items) { item in
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }

    func appendProduct() {
        let product = Product(name: self.$name.wrappedValue, quantity: 1, complated: false)
        let basicCategory = "Generic"
        let existingCategory = self.categories.items.filter({$0.categoryName == basicCategory}).first
        if (existingCategory?.items != nil) {

            // Changes here do not refresh the UI 
            existingCategory?.items.append(product)
        } else {
            let category = Category()
            category.categoryName = basicCategory
            category.items.append(product)
            self.categories.items.append(category)
        }
    }
}
```

When I append to the items of the `Category` (`existingCategory?.items.append(product)`), the UI is not updated unless I got to a different View with navigation or using a `.sheet()`

Anyone has an idea what is wrong here? I am quite new to Swift and SwfitUI.

Comment: I don't think you can have an `ObservableObject` in another `ObservableObject`.. maybe try that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your View is only observing `categories`, therefore only direct changes to `categories` will result in a redraw of your view.

This is why `self.categories.items.append(Category())` would always result in a view redraw but `existingCategory?.items.append(product)` is not.

`existingCategory?.items.append(product)` is only adding an Element to one of `categories` Category Elements, but the Category Element is still the same so no changed where made directly to the observed `categories`.

You could try this:

`self.$categories.items[0].items.wrappedValue.append(product)`

This will also always result in an redraw of your view because your operating directly on the `categories` binding.

Comment: Thank you this is the answer. To avoid using the 0 as hardcoded index I did the following:
let index = self.categories.items.firstIndex(where: { (item) -> Bool in
              item.categoryName == basicCategory
            }) ?? 0
self.$categories.items[index].items.wrappedValue.append(product)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, Category and Product should be a struct.

That gives you value semantics which is what SwiftUI uses to detect changes. I.e. a change to a Product, is detected as a change to Category, which is detected as a change to the `@Published` items, which SwiftUI is observing.